# Error in creating SessionFactory object.net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver

Tags: hibernate, byte-buddy

Error in creating SessionFactory

```
object.net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
Aug 02, 2019 2:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.tutorial.hibernate.servlets.GetDataServlet] in context with path [/MicCheck] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:58)
    at com.tutorial.hibernate.util.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:20)
    at com.tutorial.hibernate.servlets.GetDataServlet.doGet(GetDataServlet.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are lacking Byte Buddy on your class path. How are you managing your dependencies? Make sure Byte Buddy is included.